# Docker not installed and by passing download of Fabric images

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I just installed ubuntu 16.04 version and tried to install Hyperledger Fabric. I didn't even install docker and anything. But when I typed "curl -sSL URL | bash -s 1.4.0", I faced with Docker not installed, by passing download of Fabric images. Can anybody help me about this problem?

```html
traveler5260@traveler5260-VirtualBox:~$ curl -sSL URL | bash -s 1.4.0

Installing hyperledger/fabric-samples repo

===> Cloning hyperledger/fabric-samples repo and checkout v1.4.0
bash: 줄 75: git: Cannot find command

Installing Hyperledger Fabric binaries

===> Downloading version 1.4.0 platform specific fabric binaries
===> Downloading:  https://nexus.hyperledger.org/content/repositories/releases/org/hyperledger/fabric/hyperledger-fabric/linux-amd64-1.4.0/hyperledger-fabric-linux-amd64-1.4.0.tar.gz
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 50.9M  100 50.9M    0     0  2566k      0  0:00:20  0:00:20 --:--:-- 5270k
==> Done.
===> Downloading version 1.4.2 platform specific fabric-ca-client binary
===> Downloading:  https://nexus.hyperledger.org/content/repositories/releases/org/hyperledger/fabric-ca/hyperledger-fabric-ca/linux-amd64-1.4.2/hyperledger-fabric-ca-linux-amd64-1.4.2.tar.gz
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 6324k  100 6324k    0     0  1102k      0  0:00:05  0:00:05 --:--:-- 1379k
==> Done.

Installing Hyperledger Fabric docker images

=========================================================
Docker not installed, bypassing download of Fabric images
=========================================================
```

Comment: after this, I have to type "cd fabric-samples" but it still dosen't work..

Comment: you also need to install `git`  ... `bash: 줄 75: git: Cannot find command`

Comment: Oh, I see! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I didn't even install docker and anything

This is what gives you trouble. The script you are running in your terminal requests the Hyperledger binaries for your specific OS; fabric_tools, fabric_examples AND downloads all of the Docker images to generate new peers and orders (and the Chaincode Environment).

Because Docker is not found on your machine, the script is skipping this image download.

To install Docker for your specific Ubuntu distro you can follow these steps (omit the user creation if you have no problem running Docker with your root user):
https://www.vultr.com/docs/installing-docker-ce-on-ubuntu-16-04

Hope this helps you a little bit.